# How to resolve Spring framework project error org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound?

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc

I started a Spring MVC project for developing a backend and the project is here:

```
https://github.com/Chaklader/backend
```

It's just the initialization and I'm getting the following error,

```
Feb 12, 2016 2:23:42 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/myTest/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'offers'
```

Inside the `WEB-INF` folder, the `web.xml` file is as following,

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>MyBackend</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>offers</display-name>
    <servlet-name>offers</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>offers</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

and, `offers-servlet.xml` file (also, inside the `WEB-INF` folder) is as following,

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.backend.test.controllers"></context:component-scan>
    <mvc:annotation-driven></mvc:annotation-driven>
<bean id="jspViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/JSP/"></property>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

What does it mean by noHandlerFound and how to resolve the problem ? There is a similar post in the forum, but, that doesn't help.

Comment: Servlet url-pattern should be `/*`:  `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>`

Comment: I just tried, this doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It means you do not have a controller which handles the request with URI `/myTest/`. 
In your controller, you should have something like:

```
@RequestMapping("/myTest")
public String myTest(){
   return "viewName";
}
```

Comment: I followed your suggestion and also, maven update before run the server (apache tomcat v8.0). I still get the same error. Do you have any second thought ?

Comment: Your project does not seem valid maven project. It should not contain WebContent folder. Instead it should have a `src/main/java` for Java classes, and `src/main/webapp/` which contains web stuff.

Comment: I created a dynamic web project and later converted to maven project, add the dependencies and did maven update. It worked previously, but, not working now.

Comment: you can move the files manually, just create the folders by Add New Source folder eclipse feature, move WebContent stuff to src/main/webapp and java content to src/main/java

Comment: Other then moving the files, do you have any other solution ? I don't have lot of knowledge in Eclipse, however, I suspect this is not the project structure issue.

Comment: Create a new maven project, choose archetype `maven-archetype-webapp`, it will have by default these folders, and then add these files. Eclipse will get confused on deployment with such project structure.

Comment: This is good suggestion, I will try this soon. I tried maven archetype as spring-mvc and this way I was getting some other errors.  If this works, I will add the files and Spring dependencies gradually. In any way, I will update in the post, thanks.

Comment: The project structure is different than what you have mentioned, the webapp created separately.

Comment: Finally, I take a scratch project from a Udemy course and start on the top of that.

Comment: The advice for selecting maven-archetype-webapp was helpful and I started to understand the other projects clearly.